# Using NSString contents as NSArray name

Tags: objective-c

Is there a way to use the contents of an NSString as the NSArray pointer name? It's possible that this is not available, but maybe there is another method to something like this:

```
NSString*one=@"hi";
NSString*two=@"yo";

NSArray*testarray=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:one, two, nil];

NSLog(@"actual count: %i", [testarray count]);

NSString*testname=@"testarray";
NSLog(@"test count: %i",[ --insert here to get array name from testname-- count]);
```

I've tried a variety of guesses for what I could insert in there to use my `testname` as the array name for the count operation, but no dice. I know it's a bit odd, but I can foresee quite a lot of useful reasons to do this, and I'm having one right now in another app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString*one=@"hi";
NSString*two=@"yo";

NSDictionary *testDic=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
              [NSArray arrayWithObjects:one, two, nil], 
              @"testarray" ,nil];

NSLog(@"actual count: %i", [testarray count]);

NSString*testname=@"testarray";
NSLog(@"test count: %i",[[testDic objectForKey:testname] count]);
```

Comment: i think this would do it. i'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Key-Value Coding for this (see [Key Value Coding Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html)).

Note anyway that doing this kind of code — like the one in your question — is generally a bad design. If you need to do this, you should consider reviewing your code design *(that may in some rare cases be the only way to do, but at least if you need to do this you should check first it is the only solution)*

Using KVC is essentially useful for binding values to your model, or specific stuff like that, but is generally not the preferred way to do if you can avoid and use direct ivars/@properties instead.

Comment: thanks, i'll check that out. i like the solution provided ZhangChn also.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's what you need, but...

You can invoke method by its name:

```
NSString *methodName = @"...";
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(methodName);
[objectRef performSelector:selector];
```

This method may return reference to your array. It should works this way.

Comment: This is a way to go, but this is costy: I guess you will have a better performance using KVC to retrieve an ivar by its name (as it is designed for this), don't you think?